# Can you still earn cards from the Monster Summer Sale?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

When the Steam Winter Sale ended a section appeared on my badges page for the Monster Summer Sale, it wasn't there before the winter sale and I can't click into it to see the details for it like my other badges. If I click the play button it just takes me to the homepage of the store.

From what I've been able to find you need to have a level 8 steam account to get cards for this badge and my account is only level 4 so why did this badge show up? If I reach level 8 could still earn cards for it? Is it some kind of bug?

Comment: I'm level 10 and I still have the same problem.

Comment: @Montag451 level 50 here, same problem :P

Comment: Did the badge show up after the winter sale ended for you as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No, you are not able to earn cards for it anymore.**

The fact that it is displayed is probably a bug.